# SQL query persistent on inserting one specific row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My code is supposed to take data from `personprofile` table and insert it into `organandtissuedonationcommittee` table if certain conditions are met. What am I doing wrong. Please help

```
    // check the prioritylvl if 1 insert organstatus as transplant completed if 2 or 3 then organstatus as pending
// only taking whatever data is in the first row
//select name,insurnce,admissionreason 
$sqlpersonprofile= "SELECT firstname,fathername,lastname,medicalinsurance,prioritylvl,admissionreason 
                    FROM personprofile";
$patients=  mysqli_query($link,$sqlpersonprofile);
$processpriority= mysqli_fetch_assoc($patients);

$firstname= $processpriority['firstname']; 
$fathername= $processpriority['fathername']; 
$lastname= $processpriority['lastname']; 
$medinsurance= $processpriority['medicalinsurance'];
$prioritylvl= $processpriority['prioritylvl'];  
$admissionreason= $processpriority['admissionreason']; 

if($prioritylvl= 1 && $admissionreason = 5){
    $sqlcommittee= "INSERT INTO organandtissuedonationcommittee(firstname,fathername,lastname,insurance,organstatus)  
    VALUES('$firstname','$fathername','$lastname','$medinsurance','Organ donated')";
    $committee = mysqli_query($link, $sqlcommittee);

        if(!$committee){
                echo 'Not inserted';
            }

}
else{if($prioritylvl= 2 || $prioritylvl = 3 && $admissionreason = 5 ){

    $sqlcommittee= "INSERT INTO organandtissuedonationcommittee(firstname,fathername,lastname,insurance,organstatus)  
    VALUES('$firstname','$fathername','$lastname','$medinsurance','Pending')";
    $committee = mysqli_query($link, $sqlcommittee);

        if(!$committee){
                echo 'Not inserted';
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What issue are you facing now? Are you getting any error?

Comment: $prioritylvl and $admissionreason are both of type int

Comment: the code persists on adding as specific row over and over

Comment: Of course it will. Your first select statement is going to return the same rows each time it's run. How do you mark a source row as "processed"? Or since that select would return multiple rows, why aren't you looping through each row and processing it?

Comment: All of your 'tests' in your `if` statements are assignments - `$prioritylvl= 1` should be `$prioritylvl == 1`. One = is assignment, == is test equal to.

Comment: And why are you using the assignment operator (=) instead of the comparison operators (== or ===) ?

Comment: I tried the == doesn't work the problem is the same